# How do I make mail contact form in Firebase hosting?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, firebase

I'm trying to migrate my website to Firebase hosting, but I have a contact form PHP mail that I want to use in Firebase too. Can I do It? And How?

Thanks!

Comment: Add code with issue.

Comment: @artgb my code is just a regular mail() function in PHP. I wanna know how can I do it in Firebase hosting. It can be with cloud functions, but I need to know how. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create form and then submit the user data to Firebase Database and view it from your Admin Dashboard.

You can do something like this:

```
//Handling Contact Form
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', event => {
  const leadName = document.getElementById('client_name').value;
  const leadEmail = document.getElementById('client_email').value;
  const leadMobile = document.getElementById('client_mobile').value;
  const leadMessage = document.getElementById('client_message').value;

if(leadMobile != "" && leadEmail != "" && leadName != "") {

  const leadTimestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

  firebase.database().ref('leads').once('value', snapshot => {
    var totalLeads = snapshot.numChildren();
    totalLeads++;

    firebase.database().ref('leads').child(totalLeads).set({
      name: leadName,
      mobile: leadMobile,
      email: leadEmail,
      message: leadMessage,
      timestamp: leadTimestamp
    });
    $('.contact-form').hide();
    $('.message-sent-success').show();

  }, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
} else {
  alert('Please fill all the fields.');
  }
});
```

The above code takes 4 user values, generates timestamp and inserts the data in Firebase Database and if you have an admin dashboard, you can use it to view it and perform further actions on it from there.

Here's how you can send email using [emailjs.com](http://emailjs.com)

```
emailjs.send("gmail", "<template_name>", { //template_name is set via emailjs.com dashboard
      content: email_description // you can store user data in any such variable
}).then(
    function(response) {
      document.write("Email sent successfully!");
    },
    function(error) {
      document.write("Failed to send email.");
      console.log(error);
    }
);
```

Comment: This is a awesome solution, but I want that the code just mail me with the information typed in the form.

Comment: You can try the method Mariano posted below regarding sending emails using Firebase functions, I have never used Firebase functions so can't post code about that but I do regularly send emails using Javascript. For this purpose, I use emailjs.com SDK, they offer free version through which you can send 200 emails monthly. In emailjs.com, you login to dashboard, create templates which essentially means setting up title, whom will you send(this can be customized via code as well) and with just a few lines of code, you can send email whenever user clicks submit button. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 8):

[Firebase hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/) only serves static content, this means you can't use PHP or any server-side language there.

On the other hand, you can still use [Firebase functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) to [send an email](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users) using an [HTTP trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) via AJAX with Javascript.

This way, you can make a fully functional contact form without using server-side languages in your site.

Comment: Hmm nice! But How I do It? I&#39;m kinda new with backend programming. Do you have any demo or snippets to show me? Thank You!